# Python Regex sentence filtering

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to filter the following sentence

```
'I'm using C++ in high-tech applications!', said peter (in a confident way)
```

into its individual words to get

```
I'm using C++ in high-tech applications said peter in a confident way
```

what I have so far is

```
parsing=re.findall(r"\w+(?:[-']\w+)*|'|[-.(]+|\S\w*",text)
' '.join(w for w in parsing if w not in string.punctuation)
```

however this produces

```
I'm using C in high-tech applications said peter in a confident way
```

So 'C++' incorrectly turns into 'C' because '+' is in string.punctuation.  Is there anyway I can modify the regex code to allow for '+''s not to be tokenized?  Any alternative method to get the desired output would also be welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `(\w|\+)` instead of `\w`. This will use both word characters and the plus sign.

Alternatively, you could use `[a-zA-Z+]` or ideally `[\w+]` as suggested by Kyle Strand.

Comment: which \w are you referring to? there are three of them

Comment: @user1893354 All of them. The `(\w|\+)` will match normal words and also words including the plus sign in them, but using @KyleStrand's `[\w+]` is even better.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to C0deH4cker's answer but slightly simpler, replace all instances of `\w` with `[\w+]`.

```
>>> parsing=re.findall(r"[\w+]+(?:[-'][\w+]+)*|'|[-.(]+|\S[\w+]*",text)
>>> parsing
["'", "I'm", 'using', 'C++', 'in', 'high-tech', 'applications', '!', "'", ',', 'said', 'peter', '(', 'in', 'a', 'confident', 'way', ')']
>>> ' '.join(w for w in parsing if w not in string.punctuation)
"I'm using C++ in high-tech applications said peter in a confident way"
```

Note that your original solution splits "C++" into three distinct tokens, so even excluding `+` from `string.punctuation` wouldn't have solved your problem:

```
>>> parsing=re.findall(r"\w+(?:[-']\w+)*|'|[-.(]+|\S\w*",text)
>>> parsing
["'", "I'm", 'using', 'C', '+', '+', 'in', 'high-tech', 'applications', '!', "'", ',', 'said', 'r', '(', 'in', 'a', 'confident', 'way', ')']
```